# After reconnecting to my socket.io server does not receive the event sent from my android device

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I really don't see what is wrong, On an android phone, I connect to my sever node js socket.io, all the events worked. But if I cut the connection and reactivate it. The reconnection is detected by the server. But the events sent from the phone to the server are not received by the server.

I created a socket with parameters that allow reconnection :

```
private Socket socket;
{
    try {
        IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
        opts.forceNew = false;
        opts.reconnection = true;
        opts.reconnectionAttempts = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        opts.reconnectionDelay = 1000;
        opts.reconnectionDelayMax = 5000;
        socket = IO.socket(Constant.URL_SOCKET, opts);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Obviously I didn't forget to call in onCreate :

```
socket.connect();
actionSocket();
```

Here my listerner also call in onCreate :

```
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            actionSocket();
        }
    });
    socket.on(Socket.EVENT_RECONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            actionSocket();
        }
    });
```

actionSocket corresponds to this function:

```
 socket.on("toast", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             });
        }
    });
```

For test reconnection i got this button :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        socket.emit("toast", new JSONObject());
    }
});
```

Server side :

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("connection");
    addSocketListeners(socket);
});
```

And addSocketListeners()

```
function addSocketListeners(socket){
    socket.on("toast", function(data){
         socket.emit("toast", {});
    });
}
```

Hope my question is clear. Thanks to everyone who will help me.

Comment: Is it really possible to reconnect a socket? Or did you create a new socket?

Comment: No I am not creating a new instance the reconnection is really possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`off` the event when disconnect the socket and `on` when you connect every time

```
socket.off("toast");
```

EDIT : Instead of off use removeAllListeners:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on("disconnect", function(){
        socket.removeAllListeners("toast");
    });
});
```

Comment: I am trying, wait a bit

Comment: This work with removeAllListeners("toast"), Thanks man !